# How to draw a line marking where each chapter occurs in a text?

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics, string-manipulation, data, text

I am performing a text analysis on C.S. Lewis's book *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*.
I have created the following analysis of textual occurences of Aslan or Lion, Peter, Lucy, Edmund, Susan, White Witch, and Wardrobe throughout the book but would like to draw a vertical line where the word chapter occurs in the [Gutenberg Project text](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/lewiscs-thelionthewitchandthewardrobe/lewiscs-thelionthewitchandthewardrobe-00-h.html).

```
textdata = 
  Import["C:\\Users\\Peter\\Documents\\The Lion, the Witch, and the \
Wardrobe by C.S. Lewis.txt"];
mentions = 
  StringPosition[textdata, #, IgnoreCase -> True][[All, 
     1]] & /@ {"lion" | "Aslan", "Peter", "Edmund", "Lucy", "Susan", 
    "White Witch", "Wardrobe"};
SmoothHistogram[mentions, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Aslan", "Peter", "Edmund", "Lucy", "Susan", 
   "White Witch", "Wardrobe"}, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 ImageSize -> 700, PlotTheme -> "PastelColor", 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
   Automatic, {Thick, Dotted}, Dashed}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.8`]]]
chapterpositions = 
 StringPosition[textdata, "Chapter", IgnoreCase -> True]
```

[image]
I have looked through the documentation for a way to create a vertical line without success.

Comment: `Epilog->Line[{{xPos, 0}, {xPos, 1}]`

Comment: You can use `GridLines`.  For example, `Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, GridLines -> {{-1.5, -0.5, +0.5, 1.5}, None}]` (but of course replace the numbers I made up with your numbers!)